# Service + activity for playing music

Tags: java, android, android-music-player

I created simple music play but I want to play it in background, I don't know if my solution is correct:

- Service (for playing music)
- Activity with fragment (for control)

But when it is easy to play/stop/pause (getCurrentPosition and exchange data), there will be huge problem with seekbar runtime.

When I can send position via bundle, changing seekbar runtime will do nothing for me.

Can you tell me some solution?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to declare a `BroadcastReceiver` inside your service and then from your activity use 
`LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);` to send data to your service. The other way is to bind the service to your activity and get the data directly. 
There is no conflict between the onStartCommand and the onBind methods. You can start your service from the onStartCommand and bind it later.